# How to delete object, filter by extension in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Whats the best way to delete google cloud storage objects filtered by extensions? I have a bucket that contains folders with millions of .html and .jpg extension files and I'd like to automatically delete only html files older than 2 years. I want to apply a rule using Object Lifecycle Management.

I have read the [article1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) and [article2](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/google-cloud-storage-bucket-lifecycle-rules-how-to-change-them) which shows to apply rule for all objects but I only want to delete html files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done with Object Lifecycle Management. It does not have a [condition](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#conditions) to specify file extensions. I would try to craft a list of files to remove by creation date with [gsutil stat](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/stat) and [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) and then remove those files with a piped [gsutil rm](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm). Something like this should work:

```
cat filestoremove.txt | gsutil -m rm -I
```

Per the gsutil rm doc page the txt has to contain object URLs for this to work. One per line.

Comment: Correct answer. You can only filter by prefix on Cloud Storage, not suffix. you can use a micro VM to run a delete script in background. You can also use Workflow for that. Several options in fact, but none easy and obvious

Comment: Yes there are lot of options but i want to use Object Lifecycle Management to make a rule which will automatically delete files.

Comment: You can create a rule to autodelete files, but you can't specify the file extension with Object Lifecycle Management. In the question you say you only want to remove HTML  files. What you want can't be done with Object Lifecycle Management alone.